# Set emmet for stylus in Brackets

Tags: emmet, adobe-brackets

I'm using brackets, and I dicided to use stylus instead of scss. For scss emmet's snippent works great, when i've added

```
"scss": {
    "extends": "css"
}
```

to snippets.json

but

```
"styl": {
    "extends": "css"
}
```

doesn't work for stylus. I cant understand why.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add `'text/x-styl': 'stylus'` under "modeMap" in `editor.js` on line 48, and in `node_modules/emmet/lib/resolver/css.js` configure your code style on line 113